# Accessing the nth element in an irregular named range

Tags: excel, vba, solver

I have two defined ranges, A_ and B_

They are cells:
A_ is C1, F2 and K9
B_ is W1, R5 and P3

So, each name is defined over three cells. Note that the cells are NOT in a single row or column, but are irregular,

I would like to loop over the count of cells in A_ and add a constraint to solver.

Right now, I do this "by hand".

```
SolverAdd CellRef:="C1", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="W1"
SolverAdd CellRef:="F2", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="R5"
SolverAdd CellRef:="K9", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="P3"
```

How can I loop over the cells in A_ and B_ and add that way?

I tried the following:

```vb
For j=1 to A_.Count
    SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("A_")(j).Address, Relation:=1, FormulaText:=Range("B_").(j).Address
Next j
```

This did not work because Range("A_").(2) does NOT give "F2" but "C2".

Comment: Use the `Areas` property.

Answer (score 1):

### Loop Through Cells of a Non-Contiguous Range

- I don't know what the Solver is all about, but I'm sure you can adapt the following to fit your requirements:

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub countAreasAndCells()
    Dim n As Long
    Dim m As Long
    For n = 1 To Range("A_").Areas.Count
        For m = 1 To Range("A_").Areas(n).Cells.Count
            Debug.Print Range("A_").Areas(n).Cells(m).Address, _
                        Range("B_").Areas(n).Cells(m).Address
        Next m
    Next n
End Sub
```

- Note that `m` is always `1` in your case, so you can simplify:

**Simplified**

```
Sub countAreasAndCellsSimple()
    Dim n As Long
    For n = 1 To Range("A_").Areas.Count
        Debug.Print Range("A_").Areas(n).Cells(1).Address, _
                    Range("B_").Areas(n).Cells(1).Address
    Next n
End Sub
```

- In the end, this should do it:

**Final**

```
Sub SolverFinal()
    Dim j As Long
    For j = 1 To Range("A_").Areas.Count
        SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("A_").Areas(j).Cells(1).Address, _
                  Relation:=1, _
                  FormulaText:=Range("B_").Areas(j).Cells(1).Address
    Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: This is a really good approach! I usually use an array of addresses.  I will use this from now on *(+1)*

Answer (score 0):

you can take benefit of the `For Each cel in someRange` loop that iterates through a range cells following their position in the named range definition and write a helper function

```
Function GetIthCellAddress(rng As Range, nth As Long) As String
    Dim ith As Long
    Dim cel As Range
    For Each cel In rng
        ith = ith + 1
        If ith = nth Then Exit For
    Next
    GetIthCellAddress = cel.Address
End Function
```

to be used like:

```
For j = 1 To Range("A_").Count
    SolverAdd CellRef:=GetIthCellAddress(Range("A_"), j), Relation:=1, FormulaText:=GetIthCellAddress(Range("B_"), j)
Next
```

---

along this line you may want to limit the function call to only one named range

```
Dim j As Long
Dim cel As Range
For Each cel In Range("A_")
    j = j + 1
    SolverAdd CellRef:=cel.Address, Relation:=1, FormulaText:=GetIthCellAddress(Range("B_"), j)
Next
```